# Disable the Page number voice over of collection view ios during accessibility

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, accessibility

During accessibility , With a large number of items in collection view the OS reads out the collection view page number(Page 1 of 5) based on the available content inside it. But I want to disable reading out the page number alone while scrolling.